# gwt maven project flavors: WebAppCreator or gwt-maven-plugin-Archetype - what to use

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, maven

I need a maven project configuration for a gwt project. The configuration should run in Eclipse (3.7!?) and from console (mvn, jenkins...).

I tried webAppCreator delivered with gwt:

```
webAppCreator.cmd -noant -maven -XnoEclipse -out WebAppCreated com.example.MyApp
```

And gwt-maven-plugin Archetype. Both project look very similar in Eclipse but they have very different configurations (different directories, and use of different plugins). I think they will behave very different if project evolves (adding tests, resources...). Because the archetype configuration is much smaller i would think it's closer to maven conventions - but is this also better?

What are the effective differences of both configurations?

And what configuration would you suggest as starting point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always create POMs from scratch, but if you'd ask me, I'd probably choose the POM generated by the artifact.

The POM generated by the WebAppCreator launches the DevMode in `target/www`, which is weird, and it includes a `maven-clean-plugin` configuratin that simply is not needed (you shouldn't ever launch the DevMode using `src/main/webapp` as your *war* directory, so there's no need to clean it up)

The POM generated by the artifact on the other hand uses the `i18n` and `generateAsync` goals which IMO are not needed (they can be useful as *one shot* tools, but not to be run on each build; particularly the `i18n` goal).

If you ask me, none of them is a *good* starting point, but the artifact is *less bad* than the WebAppCreator.

**EDIT:** I started working on new archetypes: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes They're not totally ready yet, but they're IMO already better than the `gwt-maven-plugin` archetype or the `WebAppCreator`.

Comment: thx thomas,
my general problem is: what are the conventions (best practices) for gwt maven project. could you probably share your pom? (the main reason for me to use maven is to let the conventions do their job)

In meanwhile i tried both with eclipse 3.6 and 3.7. The problem with archetype-pom is, that the generated code (i.e. async-interface) is not in source folder. in 3.6 i have fixed it. At the end i need a configuration that works out of the box (no eclipse files in svn) for every developer - i am tired to tweak every new developers eclipse.

Comment: My very own "best practices" are to use the gwt-maven-plugin only for `gwt:compile` and `gwt:test`. I run the DevMode from within Eclipse, and I manage my RPC and i18n interfaces by-hand. Alternatively, you can have the RPC async interfaces generated in a dependency module so that they're available for coding in your GWT app (I did something similar for RequestFactory; my very own "best practices" also involve using 3 projects for shared, client and server code; I truly believe that's the way it should be done).

Comment: thx i am doing the same but started with webappcreator config. the problem with handcrafted and archetype is, that this either don't work (errors in eclipse) or i don't have google's "run as webapplication" button. Or how to get the tight connection between eclipse and maven without using webappcrator's weird configuration?

Comment: The Eclipse plugin should automatically add the GWT facet when it sees a `war` packaging and the `gwt-maven-plugin` plugin (I don't know the details but the plugin is now open-source). If that doesn't work, then report the issue at http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/

Comment: Looked at it: the use of maven-eclipse-plugin (as in WebAppCreator-generated POM) is deprecated: http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/source/browse/trunk/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.maven.e37/src/com/google/gdt/eclipse/maven/e37/configurators/AbstractGoogleProjectConfigurator.java#132 And the configurator looks for both `gwt-user` and `gwt-servlet` dependencies in addition to the `gwt-maven-plugin`.

Comment: thx for info, putting it together: at the moment there is no convention/best practice about a pom-configuration for GWT-projects (that run seamlessly in all ide) - the discussion is ongoing. In meanwhile the only choice is to take a starting config and tweak it 'til it runs in given environment. Answer accepted :-)

Comment: Thanks for putting in the work on this.  Is there any documentation on how to make these projects (generated from your archetypes) work in Eclipse?  I managed to import the Maven project from where it was created, which ended up creating 4 projects in total.  I checked out the README.md but it wasn't quite obvious how to translate those commands into the Eclipse world.

Comment: Actually I figured out most of it for Eclipse.  Create the project from the archetype as indicated in the README.md file, the Import/Existing Maven project into Eclipse.  Then, follow the steps in the README.md file, except use the Maven plugin rather than `mvn` command.  Do the steps in order (starting with running the `clean install` goal in the base (no-suffix) project, then run the goals in client and server projects to start both.  Only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to integrate with the Eclipse debugger.  This was for 4.2 64-bit on OSX 10.6.8, all plugin through Marketplace.

Comment: To debug server code, use “Debug As…” in Eclipse. For the client-side, I recommend creating a non-Maven launcher for the DevMode (I'll try to add one to the archetype), following http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/comfortable_debugging.html (I haven't checked it, I generally create mine by hand, given how easy it is). See also http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/eclipse/google_plugin.html

Comment: Thomas, could you let us know what is the current status of gwt-maven-archetypes? Is there any chance to have some sort of release or they are already stable?

Comment: They are stable (sort of). I don't think I'll ever do any formal release. BTW, I just updated them to GWT 2.6.0 and SuperDevMode.